# On a seemingly peculiar use of 「おいおいまた」

Tags: usage

In [one episode](https://youtu.be/X6Uh6yriWG4?t=11m18s) of 「BSマンガ夜話」, a TV program on comics, one guest used the "phrase" 「おいおいまた」 as below:

> あんな美人{びじん}じゃあ、赤名{あかな}リカは務{つと}まらない、っていう様{よう}な印象{いんしょう}が、**おいおいまた**。

It seems to me that 「おいおい、また」 is usually used in the sense of "what? ... again?" as in 「おいおいまた言論｛げんろん｝統制｛とうせい｝か」.

But it is used as a predicate(?) in the context above and the "what?...again?" reading doesn't seem to fit in that straightforward.

So, how should one interpret the 「おいおいまた」 here?

Comment: That is not peculiar; It is used 100% correctly.  Those are two completely different おいおい's (**there is no relation between the two**) and they are pronounced differently, too.

Comment: @l'électeur so the 「おいおい」 here is actually 「追々」, which means "(I) **gradually** got the impression that a beauty like that is not qualified for the role of Akana Rika"?

Comment: The pitch pattern of the interjection one is おいおい{HLHL} and that of 追々 doesn't have downsteps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going straight to the point,"おいおいまた" is also written as "追々{おいおい}また" that implies "また追々[話]｛はな｝します。 *I'll explain my impression further if I have time/chance again.*"
"追々また" is a relatively common expression used when you interrupt your talk though there remains many things to talk about but need not to talk in a hurry now.

日本語が十分｛じゅうぶん｝わかると判断｛はんだん｝しますので、以下｛いか｝、日本語で回答｛かいとう｝します。

質問｛しつもん｝にある以下｛いか｝の文章｛ぶんしょう｝からは「おいおいまた。」の意味｛いみ｝が正確｛せいかく｝には分かりませんでしたが、テレビの録画｛ろくが｝を実際｛じっさい｝に見｛み｝て分かりました。

> あんな美人{びじん}じゃあ、赤名{あかな}リカは務{つと}まらない、っていう様{よう}な印象{いんしょう}が、**おいおいまた**。

テレビの録画を見ますと、上の発言｛はつげん｝をした女性｛じょせい｝が、一度｛いちど｝話｛はな｝すのをやめて次｛つぎ｝の人｛ひと｝に話｛はな｝す機会｛きかい｝を与｛あた｝えています。画面｛がめん｝の流｛なが｝れから判断｛はんだん｝しますと、「おいおいまた」は「追々｛おいおい｝また」で、そのあとに次のようなフレーズが省略｛しょうりゃく｝されていると思｛おも｝います。更｛さら｝に、「おいおいまた」の前は「、（読点｛とうてん｝）」ではなく、「あります。」が省略されていると思います。

> （っていう様な印象が）**あります。**（追々また）**時間｛じかん｝があったら私の印象をさらに説明｛せつめい｝します。** *I'll explain my impression further if I have time/chance again*.

「追々また」は、「また追々しゃべります」というような意味で、話｛はな｝すことはまだあるが、緊急性｛きんきゅうせい｝もない内容｛ないよう｝なので、いったん話｛はなし｝を中断｛ちゅうだん｝するときに比較的｛ひかくてき｝普通｛ふつう｝に使｛つか｝われる表現｛ひょうげん｝です。